# OLS interpretation - if Y increases due to X increasing, can I say that if X decreases, Y will decrease with the same magnitude?

Tags: interpretation, least-squares, two-way

$$ \ln(y)=b + 0.25\ln(X) + \epsilon $$,

i.e. for $10\%$ increase in $X$, we observe about $2.5\%$ increase in $Y$.
Can I claim that if I reduce $X$ by $10\%$, then Y will drop $2.5\%$?

Can such two-way conclusions be derived always from an OLS regression? If we plot it, you can move up and down the line, the slope is always the same, therefore the answer should be Yes?

Comment: Be careful with "Y will drop": there is an error term, so even if the model is correct you're only talking about the expected value given X.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian, i get your point. I am wondering, if I can say that e.g.: 1% increase in agricultural land can result in 0.5% increase in company sales; than I can also say that if land decreases by 1%, than sales can be expected to decrease by 0.5%? Can the interpretation of OLS results be done this way, two-way?

Comment: No.  You can't say that.  As Adrian indicated, you must make this statement in terms of means, or expected values as that's what the result of OLS tells you.  But you could say, "if land decreases by 1% then sales are expected to decrease by .5% on average.

Answer (score 3):

On top of what other users said in the comments that emphasize the importance of mean, here is another alternate point of view that's too long as a comment:

You can work this out. For x to increase by 10%, the difference is:

$\ln(y_{10\%up}) - \ln(y) = b + 0.25\ln(1.1x) - b - 0.25\ln(x)$

$\ln(y_{10\%up}/y) = 0.25\ln(1.1)$

$y_{10\%up}/y = 1.024114$

Which is about 2.4% increase.

Now for 10% decrease:

$\ln(y_{10\%down}) - \ln(y) = b + 0.25\ln(0.9x) - b - 0.25\ln(x)$

$\ln(y_{10\%down}/y) = 0.25\ln(0.9)$

$y_{10\%down}/y = 0.97400037$

Which is about a 2.6% drop.

So, I guess there are two points:

1. Multiplicative interpretation like this probably does not work like usual linear regression with untransformed variables because the denominators are different.
2. The statement "when it's ln(y) and ln(x), the regression coefficient can be interpreted as elasticity" is approximated, when the coefficient gets bigger and bigger this rule of thumb may deviate more and more from the actual number.